# How do I change the camera speed in MapBox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

When you press the "up" arrow on the keyword, the camera moves "forward" with the current angle and height, etc. This makes it look sort of like a helicopter or airplane looking down on the landscape. But it goes too fast.

How do I change how fast the camera moves in this manner?

I've searched all over the manual and the Internet but found nothing, as usual.

I'm looking for some simple configuration variable such as `cameraSpeed = 0.6;`.

Comment: @TomazicM Not applicable. It's a configuration option.

Comment: @TomazicM Sadly, that page has nothing to do with the camera speed when moving around with the cursor keys. I have found it myself earlier, while searching for this. I'm almost beginning to think that it's not possible to change, which would be very odd considering how "customizable" it is.

Comment: @TomazicM I don't know what your problem or point is, but I'm using MapBox GL JS and have asked a very specific question about it.